# RxJava2 with retrofit 2 for Api call

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

In RxJava 1 I was doing something like this

```
  private void doLogin() {

        final ProjectApi service = RetrofitService.createRetrofitClient();
        staticsubscription = service.service.getLogin(new PostLoginPojo("","", new Mobsess("","","","","")))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(staticObserver);

    }
 Observer<ApiLogin> getLoginObserver = new Observer<ApiLogin>() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            staticsubscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // Called when the observable encounters an error
           // Log.d(TAG, ">>>> onError gets called : " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(ApiLogin staticData) {


        }
    };
```

Now With RxJava 2 
I am trying to convert it like this
Edited:-

```
private void doLogin(){

        final ProjectApi service = RetrofitService.createRetrofitClient();
        Disposable disposable = service.getLogin(new PostLoginPojo("","", new Mobsess("","","","","")))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(getLoginObserver());

    }

    public DisposableObserver<ApiLogin> getLoginObserver() {
    return new DisposableObserver<ApiLogin>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(ApiLogin value) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    };
}
```

Here is my Project Api

```
public interface ProjectApi {
    String login = "customer/validate";

    @POST(login)
    Observable<ApiLogin> getLogin(@Body PostLoginPojo post);
}
```

And this is the Retrofit Service:-

```
public class RetrofitService {
    private final static String API_URL = AppUrl.baseUrl ;
    public RetrofitService(){
    }
    public static ProjectApi createRetrofitClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
                addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();


        return retrofit.create(ProjectApi.class);
    }
}
```

Error: `incompatible types: void cannot be converted to Disposable`

I am getting error "incompatible type" 
on `.subscribe(getLoginObserver())`,

required "io.reacivex.disposbles.Disposable" found "Void"

What I am doing wrong here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subscribe` returns `void` now,

```
public Observer<ApiLogin> getLoginObserver()
```

should return `DisposableObserver<ApiLogin>` and then you should be able to use

```
subscribeWith(getLoginObserver());
```

Comment: That is the problem , even if I am returning DisposableObserver<ApiLogin>, it is saying that its "Void" .

Comment: post the code that is using `DisposableObserver` and the exact error your are getting. Post the definition of the definition of `getLogin` as well. and Use `subscribeWith` not `subscribe`

Comment: why are you still using `subscribe` ?

Comment: Sorry that was the problem. Thanks a lot